# VIM How to get the definition for a syntax region

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

If there a syntax region definition, how to get the definition using VimL or Python?

eg, below is a definition, how can I get the data start from `start`

```
syntax region potionString start=/\v"/ skip=/\v\\./ end=/\v"/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match `start` value till the next whitespace.

```
syntax region potionString start=/\v"/ skip=/\v\\./ end=/\v"/

redir @a
silent syntax list potionString
redir END

let def=split(@a, '\n')[1]
let start=matchstr(def, "start=\\zs.*\\ze\s")
echo start
```